# python select all but one column from multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to select all elements except one column from a multidimensional array.

I think it's something like this:
    blah[:,[1,]]

So if the array was:
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

I want to get:
    [[2,3],[5,6]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [8]: ar = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

In [9]: ar
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [11]: ar[:, 1:]
Out[11]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
res = [sub[1:] for sub in a]
```

Hope it works!